# CATransform3D UIView z Border

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, core-animation

I have a question about CATransform3D, I want to transform a view about 90 degrees(in any axis) and I want it a thick z-border 
UIView *top...
...
top.layer.transform=CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians(90), 1, 0, 0);

rotates the view but the view has 0 border width

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional layer that would be rotated by PI/2  along x axis and positioned to the boarder of your view. I believe there is no other way to get what you want, only openGL.